# tower of hanoi using stacks - Empty Stack Exception

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

I am a programming novice. Basically I am trying to implement a Tower of Hanoi using stacks. I referred to *Cracking the Code Interview* solutions and it seems to have a empty stack exception error. I re-wrote the recursion part but still get this error. Why am I getting this error?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tower {

    private Stack<Integer> disks;
    private int index;
    public Tower(int i) {
        disks = new Stack<Integer>();
        index = i;
    }

    public int index() {
        return index;
    }

    public void add(int d) {
        if(!disks.isEmpty() && disks.peek() <= d) {
            System.out.println("Error placing disk: " + d);
        }
        else {
            disks.push(d);
        }
    }

    public void moveTopTo(Tower t) {
        int top = disks.pop();
        t.add(top);
        System.out.println("Move disk " + top
                           + " from " + index() + " to " + t.index());
    }

    public void moveDisks(int n, Tower origin, Tower buffer, Tower destination) {
        if(n == 1) {
            moveTopTo(destination);
        }
        else if(n > 0) {
            moveDisks(n - 1, origin, destination, buffer);
            moveTopTo(destination);
            moveDisks(n - 1, buffer, origin, buffer);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 3;
        Tower[] towers = new Tower[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            towers[i] = new Tower(i);
        }
        for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            towers[0].add(i);
        }
        towers[0].moveDisks(n, towers[0], towers[1], towers[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? in which line are you getting the error? can you add stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks Jordi! Here they are..This is the first time I am posting a question.. got really confused about the indentation and formatting. Sorry if it is too hard to read

Comment: Adding Stacktrace and errors:
Move disk 0 from 0 to 2
Move disk 1 from 0 to 1
Error placing disk: 2
Move disk 2 from 0 to 2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
 at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
 at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
 at Tower.moveTopTo(Tower.java:26)
 at Tower.moveDisks(Tower.java:46)
 at Tower.main(Tower.java:60)

Comment: Thank you Jordi! The problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're treating `moveDisks()` as if it were static: it's taking three tower parameters. In other words, it isn't really an instance method of a particular tower at all.

But the problem is that within that code, you call `.moveToTop()`, and that certainly is an instance method: it moves a disk from this particular tower.

As a first try towards a solution, I'd try going back to the book solution, but changing it just a little:

```
public void moveDisks(int n, Tower destination, Tower buffer) {
    if(n > 0) {
        moveDisks(n - 1, buffer, destination);
        moveTopTo(destination);
        buffer.moveDisks(n - 1, destination, this);
    }
}
```

The last line is the key. We're saying:

1. Move n-1 disks from this tower to the buffer, using the destination as a buffer.
2. Move the top disk from this tower to the destination.
3. (The key bit) move n-1 disks **from the buffer** to the destination, using this tower as a buffer.

---

The alternative is to get your approach working. If you want to do that, start by declaring your `.moveDisks()` as `static`. Once you've done so, the compiler will complain about the `.moveToTop()` call, which also needs to be made static. And when you've made that static too, you'll find that you need to pass it two towers: a source and a destination.

---

At the moment, you have a mixture of the two approaches, which is why it's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. You are 100% right: When I encounter the error using the source code from the book (I mean I accidentally omitted the 'buffer.'), I tried to reuse the static version of TOH that I wrote before and clearly it messed things up.